# Video playback crashes Elonex netbook system

Tags: windows-xp, video, crash, netbook, playback

My netbook crashes when playing video files (avi, wmv). I thought it was a Windows Media Player issue, so I downloaded latest codecs, but it still didn't work. VLC player plays ridiculously slow, and Real Player media player gets about half an hour into the clip then complete system crash — I can't access the task manager, and have to power off.

It seems worse when plugged into external monitor (1080i tv) and better if given time to buffer (for want of a better term) because we are watching files from the hard drive.

Does anybody know what might be causing these problems? The computer is running Windows XP SP3.

Comment: What codecs are you using? More specs would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

Elonex's website seems to be down, so i can only speculate on the exact nature of these issues. I can see a few possible issues here - firstly that if its a netbook, its running a horribly underpowered atom processor, with a horrible graphics processor.

Without more information, i can guess at a few things - firstly whatever codecs you're using do not use hardware acceleration (and i can't seem to recall any guide that sets it up for a atom sicne they use non-intel designed IGPs). Secondly, you can't really expect to have the system to have the power to run HD.

Freezing and slowness may be due to excessive processor load (open up and have task manager always on top while playing video to check).

Solutions are tricky, try lower definition video and see if it works. Try converting it to roughly your screen resolution maybe.